# Which object library is required for send email from excel using "mailenvelope" property?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to send email through MS Excel and using the code below. The code was working fine previously. But after re-installing the windows OS & Microsoft office, the code is not working anymore. Error: "Object library not registered"

Code is as given below

```
Sub Send_email()

ActiveSheet.Range("A1:D10").Select

ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True

With ActiveSheet.MailEnvelope

.Item.to = "myemailaddress@myemail.com"
.Item.Subject = "Test EMail"
.Item.send

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you selected `Microsoft Outlook Library` from `Tools>References` ?

Comment: yes I have selected the "Microsoft Outlook Library"